# how to create a rolling calculated theory

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on this Fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2f822/1

it has the below schema and inserts:

```
create table TVD(
  PK int
  , MSR int
  , MSR_PREV int
  , ST_MSR int
  , azi float
  , azi_prev float
  , incl float
  , incl_prev float
)

insert into TVD values
(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
(2,100,0,0,2.11429185586593,0,0.00523598775598299,0),
(3,200,100,0,2.0612338466053,2.11429185586593,0.00366519142918809,0.00523598775598299),
(4,300,200,0,2.04028989558137,2.0612338466053,0.00174532925199433,0.00366519142918809),
(5,400,300,0,1.00478605037314,2.04028989558137,0.000872664625997165,0.00174532925199433)
```

The prev columns is the logical "previous" values of the other columns.  for example MSR_PREV is the logical "previous" value of the value stored in MSR.  ST_MSR is the first value of the MSR series.

I need to add a column called: TVD_VALUE
the design so far is an unfinished case statement:

```
case when MSR = MSR_PREV then MSR
     else <<PREVIOUS TVD_VALUE>>+((MSR-MSR_PREV)/2)*(COS(INCL_PREV)+COS(INCL))
```

How do I get the previous calculated value to finish the "next record"'s calculation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you're essentially doing a running total of your expression. You can use the [OVER clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) to sum the expression values from all of the previous rows.

```
select sum((case when MSR = MSR_PREV then MSR else ((MSR-MSR_PREV)/2)*(COS(INCL_PREV)+COS(INCL)) end)) 
  over(order by MSR rows unbounded preceding) as TVD_VALUE
from TVD

|          TVD_VALUE |
|--------------------|
|                  0 |
|  99.99931461237134 |
| 199.99829338441333 |
|  299.9978813897484 |
| 399.99778619682525 |
```

Comment: thank you so much.  just so I understand how it works...how does it sum the previous value to the new value?  I don't see a plus sign anywhere.  THanks again!!